# Custom view with gestures not working in storyboard

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom UIView that has some swipe gestures added, but when putting it in a controller in the storyboard, it stops recognizing the gestures.
I suppose there is some linking that I forgot, but I'm not sure how to handle it.
Any help?
Thanks!

EDIT:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame  {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DIDoubleThumbSliderView" owner:nil options:nil];

for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
{
    if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[DIDoubleThumbSliderView class]])
    {
        self = (DIDoubleThumbSliderView *)currentObject;
        break;
    }
}
if (self) {
    self.frame = frame;
}
return self;
}

- (IBAction)onLeftThumbPanned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
NSLog(@"HEY");
}
```

Comment: Have you set `Referencing outlet collection` and `Selector`

Comment: You really need to provide a lot more infos and also code.

Comment: Can you show your Coding?

Comment: Did you programmatically create the custom view or uising XIB?

Comment: Please response here

Comment: I don't really have a code, I just created the custom view in a xib (views with interaction enabled), put the gesture delegate on it (maybe that's the problem) and put it in the controller in the storyboard.
I suppose I'm missing to link it to the controller, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Ok did you create a "DIDoubleThumbSliderView.h and "DIDoubleThumbSliderView.m" files with xib?

Comment: Yes, all 3 and I put that view in the storyboard inside one view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
yourView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommended that you must use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` for swipe controller by coding. Not UIStoryboard widget.